# How to sum over subsets of rows in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm using R to work with the US county-level [voting data](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/VOQCHQ) that the good folks at MIT steward. I'd like to know the total votes each candidate got in each county. For some states, such as Wisconsin, that's easy:

```
"state", "county_name", "county_fips", "candidate", "party", "candidatevotes", "totalvotes", "mode"<br>
"WISCONSIN", "WINNEBAGO", "55139", "JO JORGENSEN", "LIBERTARIAN", 1629, 94032, "TOTAL"
```

For other states, such as Utah, it's doable:

```
"UTAH", "WEBER", "49057", "DONALD J TRUMP", "REPUBLICAN", 0, 111403, "EARLY"<br>
"UTAH", "WEBER", "49057", "DONALD J TRUMP", "REPUBLICAN", 0, 111403, "ELECTION DAY"<br>
"UTAH", "WEBER", "49057", "DONALD J TRUMP", "REPUBLICAN", 0, 111403, "MAIL"<br>
"UTAH", "WEBER", "49057", "DONALD J TRUMP", "REPUBLICAN", 65949, 111403, "TOTAL"
```

South Carolina, however, is problematic:

```
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 13656, 144050, "ABSENTEE BY MAIL"<br>
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 22075, 144050, "ELECTION DAY"<br>
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 18, 144050, "FAILSAFE"<br>
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 176, 144050, "FAILSAFE PROVISIONAL"<br>
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 22950, 144050, "IN-PERSON ABSENTEE"<br>
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "YORK", "45091", "JOSEPH R BIDEN JR", "DEMOCRAT", 133, 144050, "PROVISIONAL"
```

It seems to me that there should be some way to loop over the FIPS codes and the party name to generate the totals for each county, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Lots of possibilities over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group , if I'm interpreting the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("~/Desktop/countypres_2000-2020.csv")
#> Rows: 72617 Columns: 12
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (8): state, state_po, county_name, county_fips, office, candidate, party...
#> dbl (4): year, candidatevotes, totalvotes, version
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

df %>%
  filter(year == 2020) %>%
  group_by(candidate, county_fips) %>%
  summarise(
    county_name,
    total_votes_per_candidate_per_county = sum(candidatevotes)
    ) %>%
  relocate(candidate, .before = 4) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(county_fips)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'candidate', 'county_fips'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 11,902 × 4
#> # Groups:   candidate, county_fips [11,898]
#>    county_fips county_name candidate         total_votes_per_candidate_per_coun…
#>    <chr>       <chr>       <chr>                                           <dbl>
#>  1 01001       AUTAUGA     DONALD J TRUMP                                  19838
#>  2 01001       AUTAUGA     JOSEPH R BIDEN JR                                7503
#>  3 01001       AUTAUGA     OTHER                                             429
#>  4 01003       BALDWIN     DONALD J TRUMP                                  83544
#>  5 01003       BALDWIN     JOSEPH R BIDEN JR                               24578
#>  6 01003       BALDWIN     OTHER                                            1557
#>  7 01005       BARBOUR     DONALD J TRUMP                                   5622
#>  8 01005       BARBOUR     JOSEPH R BIDEN JR                                4816
#>  9 01005       BARBOUR     OTHER                                              80
#> 10 01007       BIBB        DONALD J TRUMP                                   7525
#> # … with 11,892 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!